# 502 Bad Gateway from relocated instance on AWS EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, django, uwsgi

I tried to move some instance from tokio region (which by the way, it's working normally) to sao paulo region, then I followed [this basic steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205963/1911787) to perform but when I launch the instance from the generated AMI and turn on, it shows me "**502 Bad Gateway**" message in browser.

The principal components on this relocated server are: nginx, uwsgi, django, supervisor, new relic.

All configurations are the same for this relocated server, so I restarted all services, it seems that nginx is working well however it has a detail to apply the next config which is config file of my site:

*nginx/sites-available/mysite*:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/site_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log;

    location /static {
        alias  /home/ubuntu/apps/site/static/;
    }

    location /media/  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/apps/site/media/;
    }

    location / {
    client_max_body_size 400M;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

To be honest, I expected it operate normally since **http://127.0.0.1:8888 is working** but I don't understand the reason why nginx conexion is broken, I need some help so that I can research a little more. I checked log files, according to this file:

*/var/log/nginx/site_error.log*

```
2015/04/06 15:34:31 [error] 832#0: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)
while connecting to upstream, client:
190.233.157.2, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
"http://127.0.0.1:8888/favicon.ico", host: "54.207.136.99"
```

By what I'm going to verify the conexion again and it's what shows me:

```
$ ping 127.0.0.1

PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
```

And then I tried it with curl and after about 30 seconds, it prints the following:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8888

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm having this strange error, what does it mean really ?

Comment: Is the new node in the same security groups that the old one was?

Comment: yep, basically is a clone security group of the old instance

Comment: Possible cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464952/502-bad-gateway-from-relocated-instance-on-aws-ec2

Comment: It's the same, I thought it also would be more appropriate to post over here